# C++ initializing token

Tags: c++

I read Bjarne C++ book regarding token initializing.

the code:

```
class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value
    Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};
```

Why must make Token twice 'for char ch'

- Token (char ch) and
- Token (char ch, double val)

Thanks.

Comment: What if it has no value? Then what kind of value you would pass in as `val`?

Comment: Bad Bjarne, there should be an `explicit` on that first constructor.

Comment: @JackAidley Actually this may be the intended usage. If you have both of these constructors, you have a conversion constructor as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. You can use the following instead:

```
Token(char ch, double val = 0)
    :kind(ch), value(val) { }
```

Basically, what this (and Bjarne's) code does is allow you to construct `Token` from either:

- a `char`; or
- a `char` and a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The author probably did that to show the concept of constructor overloading at the same time,
you could instead use the following

```
Token(char ch, double val = 0) : kind(ch), value(val) {}
```

In this way the default value for val is 0, and if you want to pass any other value the zero will be overwritten with that value